# File watcher for Cython in Pycharm

Tags: cython, pycharm

Cython's `*.pyx` files need to be compiled for it to function with other `py` files. Because of this, I would like a file watcher for PyCharm just like for `*.coffee` files and for `*.ts` files.

How would one create a file watcher for Cython in Pycharm. A step by step tutorial would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need a file watcher? How should it resolve pyx dependencies on external C libraries, for example?
Why not to utilize external tools, as thoroughly explained [in previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36880336/setup-of-pycharm-for-cython)?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be "Compile on Save".

As an example, in Netbeans the "Compile on Save" feature can be enabled via "Build -> Compiling"

As for the python-demon itself, you could start it by using `gunicorn`, store md5 hash for each file, revalidate them all the time, and rebuild as soon as hash key was changed for the file.