# Setup of PyCharm for Cython

Tags: pycharm, cython

I see that [PyCharm supports Cython](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/cython-support.html).

I could always compile and run in terminal, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in PyCharm. In the link it says: "Compilation is done using external tools. The preferred build systems (Makefile, setup.py, etc.) should be configured as external tools." I'm wondering how to do this configuration. A small Hello World example in PyCharm using Cython would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Answering my own question here:

Let's say we have the function *fib.pyx*:

```
def fib(n):
"""Print the Fibonacci series up to n."""
a, b = 0, 1
while b < n:
    print b,
    a, b = b, a + b
```

There are two ways to compile and run this

1. Use a setup file. Make the file *setup.py*:

   ```
   from distutils.core import setup
   from Cython.Build import cythonize

   ext_options = {"compiler_directives": {"profile": True}, "annotate": True}
   setup(
       ext_modules = cythonize("fib.pyx", **ext_options)
   )
   ```

   The `ext_options` is included here to generate the html file with annotations. To run this file you have to go to *Tools --> Run setup.py Task*. Then type in `build_ext` as *task name* and when prompted for *Command Line* input type `--inplace`. The files *fib.c*, *fib.o* and the executable file *fib.so* is generated. The annotation file *fib.html* is also created.

   Now, the following code should work in any python file, for example *main.py*:

   ```
   import fib
   fib.fib(2000)
   ```
2. The much easier way to go is to use *pyximport*. No setup file is needed. Note that this can only be used if ["your module doesn’t require any extra C libraries or a special build setup."](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html) The file *main.py* should now look like:

   ```
   import pyximport; pyximport.install()
   import fib
   fib.fib(2000)
   ```

   As far as I understand the same compilation of code takes place even though the *fib.c*, *fib.o* and *fib.so* files don't end up in the project folder. The *fib.html* code is not generated either, but this can be fixed by adding two lines to the main file. With the new lines *main.py* is now:

   ```
   import pyximport; pyximport.install()
   import subprocess
   subprocess.call(["cython", "-a", "fib.pyx"])
   import fib
   fib.fib(2000)
   ```

Comment: In addition to these instructions, we also have to ensure that PyCharm knows that the package fodler contains a Python module, or else it will ignore it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40203488/pycharm-does-not-recognize-cython-modules-located-in-path

Comment: how can I add a function that is inside a package? I mean my main.py is in the root, and I have a package named "my_package" and there I have "my_py_file.py" and inside there "my_function()". If I refactor my "my_py_file.py" to "my_py_file.pyx" and use your second method, I get the error in main.py:   import my_package.my_py_file as mpf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package.my_py_file'

Comment: I have a question regarding debugging a Cython code in PyCharm https://stackoverflow.com/q/54014959/2227222. Would you care to take a look and see if you have any advice?